# Odd `gawk` filtering of very small floating point number

Tags: awk, floating-point

`gawk` filters out very small positive number differently depending on threshold used, but all thresholds should retain the entry.

Example input file, `tmp`:

```
A 3.92e-373
B 5e-300    
C 5e-20
D 5e-6
E 5e-3
```

Output:

```
% gawk '$2 < 5e-4' tmp
B 5e-300
C 5e-20
D 5e-6

% gawk '$2 < 5e-8' tmp
A 3.92e-373
D 5e-300
C 5e-20
```

Note `gawk '$2 < 5e-4'` should retain entry as `$2 < 3.92e-373`, which works for `gawk '$2 < 5e-8'`.

Clearly this is issue with limit of floating point, but I find it odd that the result is not consistent for both thresholds. Shouldn't `gawk` simply limit `3.92e-373` to `0` and thus print this line under all circumstances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't assume that gawk can figure out what's a number vs a string given your input and hard-coded values. Make sure they're treated as numbers by using `strtonum()` on them:

```
$ gawk 'strtonum($2) < strtonum("5e-4")' file
A 3.92e-373
B 5e-300
C 5e-20
D 5e-6

$ gawk 'strtonum($2) < strtonum("5e-8")' file
A 3.92e-373
B 5e-300
C 5e-20
```

You can see what types gawk thinks it's dealing with by calling typeof() on each:

```
$ gawk '{print typeof($2), $2, typeof(5e-4), 5e-4, strtonum($2), strtonum("5e-4")}' file | column -t
string  3.92e-373  number  0.0005  0       0.0005
strnum  5e-300     number  0.0005  5e-300  0.0005
strnum  5e-20      number  0.0005  5e-20   0.0005
strnum  5e-6       number  0.0005  5e-06   0.0005
strnum  5e-3       number  0.0005  0.005   0.0005
```

So it looks like the `strtonum("5e-4")` is redundant but IMHO it improves clarity so I'd keep it.

Notice that gawk doesn't automatically recognize `3.92e-373` as a number and so the comparison for that input would be string vs number and that's done as a string comparison (see the table at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Typing-and-Comparison).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, much appreciated. It fixed my problem **and** I learned something new! Also, another solution I found was to use a later version of `gawk` with support for arbitrary precision using the `-M` flag.